# I am not the getting the code coverage for the following lines shown in image

Tags: apex, unit-test, scheduled-apex, code-coverage

[image: console code coverage]

Here is my schedule class :

```
global class Scheduler_class implements Schedulable{
public static String CRON_EXP = '0 00 00 * * ?'; //Every Day at Midnight
    global static String scheduleMe() {
        Scheduler_class SC = new Scheduler_class(); 
        return System.schedule('b1', CRON_EXP, SC);
    }
    global void execute(SchedulableContext sc) {
         batchprocessopportunity b1 = new  batchprocessopportunity();
        ID batchprocessid = Database.executeBatch(b1,50);           
    }
}
```

and here is my test class:

```
@isTest
private class TestScheduler_class {
    static testMethod void myTestMethod() {        
   Test.startTest();
      String jobId = System.schedule('testBasicScheduledApex',Scheduler_class.CRON_EXP, new Scheduler_class());
   // Get the information from the CronTrigger API object 
      CronTrigger ct = [SELECT Id, CronExpression, TimesTriggered,NextFireTime FROM CronTrigger WHERE id = :jobId];
   // Verify the expressions are the same   
      System.assertEquals(Scheduler_class.CRON_EXP, ct.CronExpression);
   // Verify the job has not run     
      System.assertEquals(0, ct.TimesTriggered);
   // Verify the next time the job will run   
     System.assertEquals('2014-05-13 00:00:00', String.valueOf(ct.NextFireTime));
       Test.stopTest();

   }
    }
```

Help me to get the code coverage for the following lines red in color.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding this line to your test:

```
Scheduler_class.scheduleMe();
```